# NameError: name 'correct_answer' is not defined

Tags: python

So I was playing around with a small project and keep running into the same NameError over and over again. Here's the code that has the problem:

```
import time 
import random

print("Here is a practice riddle for you:")
riddler = ["What is nowhere but everywhere, except where something is?", "What is 
green and then red?","What is strong enough to smash ships but still fears the 
sun?","The more you cut me the bigger I grow. What am I?"," A diamond plate, a 
glowing grate, a place you never leave. Where am I?"]
answers = ["Nothing", "Frog in a blender", "Ice", "A hole", "Home"]
riddle = print (random.choice(riddler))

if riddle == [riddler[0]]:
    correct_answer = [answers[0]]
elif riddle == [riddler[1]]:
    correct_answer = [answers[1]]
elif riddle == [riddler[2]]:
    correct_answer = [answers[2]]
elif riddle == [riddler[3]]:
    correct_answer = [answers[3]]
elif riddle == [riddler[4]]:
    correct_answer = [answers[4]]

print (correct_answer)
```

Everytime I run the code I get this error:

Here is a practice riddle for you:
A diamond plate, a glowing grate, a place you never leave. Where am I?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/smoak//test/riddler.py", line 21, in 
print (correct_answer)
NameError: name 'correct_answer' is not defined

Comment: you define riddle as the return of the print function , which is none.
Try to print riddle you'll figure it out.

Comment: what if none of the conditions evaluate true? You should either use a final else or initialize `correct_answer` to some default value before the conditionals.

Comment: You also compare it against a list which it also never will be

Comment: any condition not match so it returns the not defined. you need to defined the correct_answer before start loop or put else in last and return correct_answer to None or blank

Comment: any condition not match so it returns the not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use print in random choice which returns **None** and avoid using  array for **IF** since random choice will return you string not an array.

```
import time 
import random

print("Here is a practice riddle for you:")
riddler = ["What is nowhere but everywhere, except where something is?", "What is green and then red?","What is strong enough to smash ships but still fears the sun?","The more you cut me the bigger I grow. What am I?"," A diamond plate, a glowing grate, a place you never leave. Where am I?"]
answers = ["Nothing", "Frog in a blender", "Ice", "A hole", "Home"]
riddle =  random.choice(riddler)

if riddle == riddler[0]:
    correct_answer = answers[0]
elif riddle == riddler[1]:
    correct_answer = answers[1]
elif riddle == riddler[2]:
    correct_answer = answers[2]
elif riddle == riddler[3]:
    correct_answer = answers[3]
elif riddle == riddler[4]:
    correct_answer = answers[4]

print (correct_answer)
```